# Вывод сообщения об ошибке

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Есть форма с selectами, помогите, пожалуйста, написать цикл для вывода сообщения об ошибке, когда value = "Select".

```css
.question > .error > p {
    display:none;
    color:red;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<form>
                <table>
                    <tr class="question">
                        <td class="titleselect">Preferred language</td>
                        <td class="theselect">
                            <select>
                                <option>Select</option>
                                <option>English</option>
                                <option>Spanish</option>
                                <option>Russian</option>
                            </select>
                        </td>
                        <td class="error"><p>Select preferred language!</p></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="question">
                        <td class="titleselect">Marital status</td>
                        <td class="theselect">
                            <select>
                                <option>Select</option>

                                <option>Single</option>
                                <option>Divorced</option>
                            </select>
                        </td>
                        <td class="error"><p>Select your marital status!</p></td>

                    </tr>
                    <tr class="question">
                        <td class="titleselect">Age</td>
                        <td class="theselect">
                            <select>
                                <option>Select</option>

                                <option>18-25 years</option>
                                <option>25-30 years</option>
                                <option>30-35 years</option>
                            </select>
                        </td>
                        <td class="error"><p>Select your age!</p></td>

                    </tr>
                    <tr class="question">
                        <td class="titleselect">Height</td>
                        <td class="theselect">
                            <select>
                                <option>Select</option>

                                <option>5'1"</option>
                                <option>5'2"</option>
                                <option>5'3"</option>
                            </select>
                        </td>
                        <td class="error"><p>Select your height!</p></td>

                    </tr>
                    <tr class="question">
                        <td class="titleselect">Weight</td>
                        <td class="theselect">
                            <select>
                                <option>Select</option>

                                <option>80-90 lbs</option>
                                <option>90-94 lbs</option>
                            </select>
                        </td>
                        <td class="error"><p>Select your weight!</p></td>

                    </tr>
                    <tr class="question">
                        <td class="titleselect">Ethnicity</td>
                        <td class="theselect">
                            <select>
                                <option>Select</option>

                                <option>Caucasian / white</option>
                            </select>
                        </td>
                        <td class="error"><p>Select your ethnicity!</p></td>

                    </tr>
                    <tr class="question">
                        <td class="titleselect">Hair color</td>
                        <td class="theselect">
                            <select>
                                <option>Select</option>

                                <option>Red</option>
                                <option>Green</option>
                                <option>Blue</option>
                            </select>
                        </td>
                        <td class="error"><p>Select your hair color!</p></td>

                    </tr>
                    <tr class="question">
                        <td class="titleselect">Children</td>
                        <td class="theselect">
                            <select>
                                <option>Select</option>

                                <option>No</option>
                                <option>Yes</option>
                            </select>
                        </td>
                        <td class="error"><p>Select Children!</p></td>

                    </tr>
                    <tr class="question">
                        <td class="titleselect">Attitude to drugs</td>
                        <td class="theselect">
                            <select>
                                <option>Select</option>

                                <option>Negative</option>
                            </select>
                        </td>
                        <td class="error"><p>Select your attitude to drugs!</p></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </form>
```

Comment: А вы сами пробовали что-то делать?

Comment: @Vartlok, пыталась цикл написать, не вышло (((

Comment: тогда добавьте пример цикла, который вы писали, мы вам подскажем что у вас не так.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<form>
    <table>
        <tr class="question">
            <td class="titleselect">Preferred language</td>
            <td class="theselect">
                <select>
                    <option>Select</option>
                    <option>English</option>
                    <option>Spanish</option>
                    <option>Russian</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td class="error"><p>Select preferred language!</p></td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="question">
            <td class="titleselect">Marital status</td>
            <td class="theselect">
                <select>
                    <option>Select</option>

                    <option>Single</option>
                    <option>Divorced</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td class="error"><p>Select your marital status!</p></td>

        </tr>
        <tr class="question">
            <td class="titleselect">Age</td>
            <td class="theselect">
                <select>
                    <option>Select</option>

                    <option>18-25 years</option>
                    <option>25-30 years</option>
                    <option>30-35 years</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td class="error"><p>Select your age!</p></td>

        </tr>
        <tr class="question">
            <td class="titleselect">Height</td>
            <td class="theselect">
                <select>
                    <option>Select</option>

                    <option>5'1"</option>
                    <option>5'2"</option>
                    <option>5'3"</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td class="error"><p>Select your height!</p></td>

        </tr>
        <tr class="question">
            <td class="titleselect">Weight</td>
            <td class="theselect">
                <select>
                    <option>Select</option>

                    <option>80-90 lbs</option>
                    <option>90-94 lbs</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td class="error"><p>Select your weight!</p></td>

        </tr>
        <tr class="question">
            <td class="titleselect">Ethnicity</td>
            <td class="theselect">
                <select>
                    <option>Select</option>

                    <option>Caucasian / white</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td class="error"><p>Select your ethnicity!</p></td>

        </tr>
        <tr class="question">
            <td class="titleselect">Hair color</td>
            <td class="theselect">
                <select>
                    <option>Select</option>

                    <option>Red</option>
                    <option>Green</option>
                    <option>Blue</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td class="error"><p>Select your hair color!</p></td>

        </tr>
        <tr class="question">
            <td class="titleselect">Children</td>
            <td class="theselect">
                <select>
                    <option>Select</option>

                    <option>No</option>
                    <option>Yes</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td class="error"><p>Select Children!</p></td>

        </tr>
        <tr class="question">
            <td class="titleselect">Attitude to drugs</td>
            <td class="theselect">
                <select>
                    <option>Select</option>

                    <option>Negative</option>
                </select>
            </td>
            <td class="error"><p>Select your attitude to drugs!</p></td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <button id="btnSubmit">Submit</button>
</form>

<script>
    $(function(){
        $('#btnSubmit').click(function(){    
            var selects = $('.theselect select');
            var valid = true;

            for(var i = 0, len = selects.length; i < len; i++){
                var currentSelect = selects[i];

                if(currentSelect.value === 'Select'){
                   valid = false;

                   var parent = $(currentSelect).parent().parent();               
                   var errorElement = $(parent).find('.error p').get(0);

                    $(errorElement).show();
                }
            }

            return valid;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
// JS
function check(e){
Array.prototype.forEach.call(this.parentNode.querySelectorAll('.question select'), function(e){
    e.parentNode.parentNode.querySelector('.error p').style.display = e.value == 'Select' ? 'block' : 'none';
  });
  e.preventDefault();
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(){
  document.querySelector('input[type="submit"]').addEventListener('click', check);
});

// jQuery
/*
$(function(){
  $('input[type="submit"]').on('click', function(e){
    $(this).parent().find('.question select').each(function(el){
      var $this = $(this);
        $this.parent().parent().find('.error p').css({'display': ($this.val() == 'Select' ? 'block' : 'none')});
    });
    e.preventDefault();
  });
});
*/
```

```css
.error > p {
    display:none;
    color:red;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <table>
    <tr class="question">
      <td class="titleselect">Preferred language</td>
      <td class="theselect">
        <select>
          <option>Select</option>
          <option>English</option>
          <option>Spanish</option>
          <option>Russian</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td class="error"><p>Select preferred language!</p></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="question">
      <td class="titleselect">Marital status</td>
      <td class="theselect">
        <select>
          <option>Select</option>

          <option>Single</option>
          <option>Divorced</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td class="error"><p>Select your marital status!</p></td>

    </tr>
    <tr class="question">
      <td class="titleselect">Age</td>
      <td class="theselect">
        <select>
          <option>Select</option>

          <option>18-25 years</option>
          <option>25-30 years</option>
          <option>30-35 years</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td class="error"><p>Select your age!</p></td>

    </tr>
    <tr class="question">
      <td class="titleselect">Height</td>
      <td class="theselect">
        <select>
          <option>Select</option>

          <option>5'1"</option>
          <option>5'2"</option>
          <option>5'3"</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td class="error"><p>Select your height!</p></td>

    </tr>
    <tr class="question">
      <td class="titleselect">Weight</td>
      <td class="theselect">
        <select>
          <option>Select</option>

          <option>80-90 lbs</option>
          <option>90-94 lbs</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td class="error"><p>Select your weight!</p></td>

    </tr>
    <tr class="question">
      <td class="titleselect">Ethnicity</td>
      <td class="theselect">
        <select>
          <option>Select</option>

          <option>Caucasian / white</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td class="error"><p>Select your ethnicity!</p></td>

    </tr>
    <tr class="question">
      <td class="titleselect">Hair color</td>
      <td class="theselect">
        <select>
          <option>Select</option>

          <option>Red</option>
          <option>Green</option>
          <option>Blue</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td class="error"><p>Select your hair color!</p></td>

    </tr>
    <tr class="question">
      <td class="titleselect">Children</td>
      <td class="theselect">
        <select>
          <option>Select</option>

          <option>No</option>
          <option>Yes</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td class="error"><p>Select Children!</p></td>

    </tr>
    <tr class="question">
      <td class="titleselect">Attitude to drugs</td>
      <td class="theselect">
        <select>
          <option>Select</option>

          <option>Negative</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td class="error"><p>Select your attitude to drugs!</p></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <input type='submit' value='Check!' />
</form>
```